# How can I change the color of the UINavigationBar&UIToolbar dynamically/immediately/on-demand?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm looking to change the colors of things like the UINavigationBar, UITabBar, etc.

I have a section in my application called "My Themes". The user, when logged in, can go to this section and select 1 of various color themes such as "Night Theme", where I color many of the view's in very dark shades.

When I first launch the application, I call a piece of code...

```
[[ColorManager sharedManager] updateApplicationColors];
```

This method, `updateApplicationColors`, will pull in a custom Theme object from NSUserDefaults, pulling in the last Theme object that was being used. This object holds the colors for various things like the NavigationBar, ToolBar, TabBar, etc.

Then after pulling it in, in proceeds to use the Theme object's colors to set various view's appearance proxy's.

Such as...

```
...
[[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor:tabBarBarTintColor];
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:tabBarTextColor];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:navigationBarTintColor];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:navigationTintColor];
[[UIToolbar appearance] setBarTintColor:toolBarBarTintColor];
[[UIToolbar appearance] setTintColor:toolBarTintColor];
...
```

Now, only certain things happen immediately, such as `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLight______];`. However, the rest does not take effect right away.

The NavigationBar's color don't get changed until I pop the 'My Themes' view off the navcontroller stack, and then change which Tab in the TabBar I'm on. As soon as I switch, the NavigationBar color change takes effect.

However, the ToolBar color doesn't change under the same circumstances. I can kill the app from multitasking, and open it again, and I see the new color in effect. The only other way I can get the color to change is after selecting a theme, then present a MFMailComposeViewController. Then if I press cancel, the TabBar will now have the new color.

How can I get it so these color changes take effect immediately after the user presses the Theme in the "My Themes" view?